# Pass a value from javascript to php

Tags: javascript, php

I want to send the value of address to a new PHP page

```
<script>  
    var address = place.formatted_address;  
    document.getElementById('af').innerHTML = address;  
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**PHP runs on the server and Javascript runs on the client**, so you can't set a PHP variable to equal a Javascript variable without sending the value to the server. You can, however, set a Javascript variable to equal a PHP variable:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var foo = '<?php echo $foo ?>';
</script>
```

To send a Javascript value to PHP you'd need to use AJAX. With jQuery, it would look something like this (most basic example possible):

```
var variableToSend = 'foo';
$.post('file.php', {variable: variableToSend});
```

On your server, you would need to receive the variable sent in the post:

```
$variable = $_POST['variable'];
```

Comment: I have already tried this on. It did not work for me with the error   

Undefined index: variable.